# HP OfficeJet 6600 printer color too dark

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, hp-officejet, icc

Images from from OfficeJet 660 are consistently dark, printing from any computer.

HP Genuine cartridges installed and I've gone through all 3 stages of cleaning. Is there a way to change the color profile to get it to lighten up!

[image: colors not matching]

Comment: HP have a long page about setting up the colour profiles: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00286904

Comment: @Mokubai - my HP software doesn't have these options.

Comment: There are several things going on besides color calibration.  The paper will make a significant difference (photo paper vs. bright white bond vs. regular), and the color and brightness of the room light will affect the printout but not the screen image.  You can see the brightness difference comparing the paper to the screen in the picture.  But the color calibration is also way off on the printer (much less saturation; the color mixes are closer to grey).